# Training solr to recognize nicknames or name variants

Tags: solr, names, synonym

I'm pretty sure that solr can be set up to recognize synonyms during searches. I'm wondering if it's possible to do the same with nicknames -- so for example searches for "Robert" would pull up records with "Bob" in them.

Answer (score 5):

Just found a page where someone named Jon Moniaci exactly how to do this: 
http://bitsandpieces.jonmoniaci.com/2010/05/searching-common-nicknames-in-solr/

Basically, create a synonyms file with lines like so:

```
Bob, Robert, Bobby
```

(Jon's file is [here](http://bitsandpieces.jonmoniaci.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/english_names.txt), derived from the listing of common male and female nicknames on http://usefulenglish.ru/)

Save to `english_names.txt` and add the following to your solr configuration:

```
<fieldType name="textEnglishName" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="english_names.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Then designate the author field as a `textEnglishName` field:

```
<fields>
  <field name="name" type="textEnglishName" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
</fields>
```